# VOTE UP answers for own question even low reputation for new users

Tags: feature-request, new-users, up-votes

I think it should be possible to vote up answers for your own questions even you have less than 15 reputations. New users can't vote up answers for their questions right now.

Comment: Is this question unclear or not useful, and why?

Comment: Votes on Meta are not meant for this, but rather to say "I agree" or "I disagree". From the [FAQ](http://meta.superuser.com/faq#reputation): *Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.*

Comment: I understood that. My suggestion was for main site.

Comment: I know. I meant the downvotes YOU got on this question. They just mean that people disagree.

Comment: Excellent observation. +1

Answer (score 9):

Let's see:

- **Ask a question**
  If it's good you get THREE upvotes... and you can upvote.
- **Post ONE good answer**
  Have it voted up, just TWICE, or get it right... and you're there.
- **Link an existing account**
  If you already have a Stack Exchange account elsewhere with at least 200 rep and you link it, you get 100 reputation!

It isn't that hard to get 15 reputation. Getting that reputation basically means that you've bothered to make an effort and have contributed to the site.

Comment: Correction: "If you already have a Stack Exchange account elsewhere **that has at least 200 reputation on it**, you get 100 reputation!".

Comment: fixed. nearly 3 years on ;p

Answer (score 6):

Here's a list of similar / duplicate requests on the main Meta.StackOverflow site:

- [Shouldn't a rep-less newbie at least be able to upvote a good answer to his/her own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/shouldnt-a-rep-less-newbie-at-least-be-able-to-upvote-a-good-answer-to-his-her-o)
- [Allow upvote for <15 rep users on own questions [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88560/allow-upvote-for-15-rep-users-on-own-questions)
- [Allow new users to vote on answers they've received [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38834/allow-new-users-to-vote-on-answers-theyve-received)
- [Why is 15 reputation required to upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-is-15-reputation-required-to-upvote)

I guess you can read through them to get the idea why users want the ability, and why it is declined.

The main idea is: With 1 rep, you haven't gained any trust yet. The site only trusts you voting until you've proven that you've understood the system (i.e. by asking a good question or posting a good answer).